# How to trim CIDR notation off an IP?

Tags: php, trim, cidr

I want to get rid of the CIDR notation and tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work like this:

```
<?php
  $txt='156.67.0.0/16';
  $re='(\\/)'.'(\\d+)';

  $end = rtrim($txt,$re);
  echo $end;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('~/.*~', '', $txt);
```

This removes everything starting the slash.

Answer (score 2):

`trim()` doesn't accept a regex but a caracter list. You can simply split the string and only use the first part though:

```
$parts = explode('/', $str);
echo $parts[0];
```

Comment: How about strtok instead of the cumbersome explode?

Answer (score 0):

`rtrim` accepts a character list, not a regular expression. Look into `preg_replace`.

```
$end = preg_replace('@/.*$@', '', $txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace()`:

```
$ip = '156.67.0.0/16';
$ip = preg_replace('#/\d+$#', '', $ip);

echo $ip; // 156.67.0.0
```